# roc_auc_score is coming as 0 test accuracy 97% possible?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, roc, auc

Edit (apologies, should have posted more details indeed):

Following is the whole code example.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import random
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras import backend as K
from sklearn import metrics

num_classes = 10
epochs = 2


def euclidean_distance(vects):
    x, y = vects
    return K.sqrt(K.maximum(K.sum(K.square(x - y), axis=1, keepdims=True), K.epsilon()))


def eucl_dist_output_shape(shapes):
    shape1, shape2 = shapes
    return (shape1[0], 1)


def contrastive_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    '''Contrastive loss from Hadsell-et-al.'06
    http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/hadsell-chopra-lecun-06.pdf
    '''
    margin = 1
    return K.mean(y_true * K.square(y_pred) +
                  (1 - y_true) * K.square(K.maximum(margin - y_pred, 0)))


def create_pairs(x, digit_indices):
    '''Positive and negative pair creation.
    Alternates between positive and negative pairs.
    '''
    pairs = []
    labels = []
    n = min([len(digit_indices[d]) for d in range(num_classes)]) - 1
    for d in range(num_classes):
        for i in range(n):
            z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[d][i + 1]
            pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
            inc = random.randrange(1, num_classes)
            dn = (d + inc) % num_classes
            z1, z2 = digit_indices[d][i], digit_indices[dn][i]
            pairs += [[x[z1], x[z2]]]
            labels += [1, 0]
    return np.array(pairs), np.array(labels)


def create_base_network(input_shape):
    '''Base network to be shared (eq. to feature extraction).
    '''
    input = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Flatten()(input)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    return Model(input, x)


def compute_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    '''Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    pred = y_pred.ravel() < 0.5
    return np.mean(pred == y_true)


def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    '''Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
    '''
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.cast(y_pred < 0.5, y_true.dtype)))


# the data, split between train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255
input_shape = x_train.shape[1:]

# create training+test positive and negative pairs
digit_indices = [np.where(y_train == i)[0] for i in range(num_classes)]
tr_pairs, tr_y = create_pairs(x_train, digit_indices)

digit_indices = [np.where(y_test == i)[0] for i in range(num_classes)]
te_pairs, te_y = create_pairs(x_test, digit_indices)

# network definition
base_network = create_base_network(input_shape)

input_a = Input(shape=input_shape)
input_b = Input(shape=input_shape)

# because we re-use the same instance `base_network`,
# the weights of the network
# will be shared across the two branches
processed_a = base_network(input_a)
processed_b = base_network(input_b)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance,
                  output_shape=eucl_dist_output_shape)([processed_a, processed_b])

model = Model([input_a, input_b], distance)

# train
rms = RMSprop()
model.compile(loss=contrastive_loss, optimizer=rms, metrics=[accuracy])
model.fit([tr_pairs[:, 0], tr_pairs[:, 1]], tr_y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=([te_pairs[:, 0], te_pairs[:, 1]], te_y))

# compute final accuracy on training and test sets
    y_pred = model.predict([tr_pairs[:, 0], tr_pairs[:, 1]])
tr_acc = compute_accuracy(tr_y, y_pred)
y_pred = model.predict([te_pairs[:, 0], te_pairs[:, 1]])
te_acc = compute_accuracy(te_y, y_pred)

print('* Accuracy on training set: %0.2f%%' % (100 * tr_acc))
print('* Accuracy on test set: %0.2f%%' % (100 * te_acc))

roc_auc_score = metrics.roc_auc_score(te_y, 1-y_pred)
print("roc_auc_score:  %0.2f" % roc_auc_score)
```

I am trying to learn the **contrastive loss** function usage with **Siamese network**. I started with [the Keras example here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese.py). I am trying to plot the [`roc_auc_score` from the scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) and it gives me 0.00

```
Train on 108400 samples, validate on 17820 samples
Epoch 1/2
108400/108400 [==============================] - 6s 52us/step - loss: 0.0930 - accuracy: 0.8910 - val_loss: 0.0420 - val_accuracy: 0.9582
Epoch 2/2
108400/108400 [==============================] - 5s 49us/step - loss: 0.0390 - accuracy: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.0295 - val_accuracy: 0.9710
* Accuracy on training set: 97.80%
* Accuracy on test set: 96.82%
roc_auc_score:  0.01
```

I feel like something is definitely wrong here. Like positive label and the negative label might not get passed to the `roc_auc_score` in correct way.

Is there anybody who has some idea why is this happening and how can I solve the issue without manually setting the `pos_label`. Please let me know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Show us how you are calling `roc_auc_score` please.

Comment: Apologies for the insufficient details, I added the whole code here. Please see. Thank you for the edit and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ROC curve is obtained by thresholding the scores, and this is usually done with the greater than operator ( > ), but the distances produced by the model have the other ordering, where closer to zero means two samples are similar, and larger distances mean dissimilar samples. This means these scores (your distances) have to be thresholded using the < operator.

A simple solution is to flip your model's predictions:

```
>>> metrics.roc_auc_score(tr_y, 1.0 - y_pred)
0.9954217433041488
```

Substracting one from your model predictions means that they can now be thresholded using the > operator, making the AUC now make sense.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes sense now why is it like this. Also, do you think this is the alternative way to do what you suggested here? `fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(te_y, y_pred,pos_label=0)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
print(roc_auc) ` this results to .99 as well. Please let me know what do you think? Thank you for your time :)